# What is the name/type of this pattern?

Tags: patterns

This is a pretty popular background pattern in web/graphic design and I'd love to find different but similar variations of it. What would I search for to find such patterns?

[image: Pattern]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a colored grid noise pattern.

I recommend http://subtlepatterns.com/ for such patterns. You can use the resources from this website for free in any of your projects.

Greetings,
Sven